# Connecting an embed web part to a hidden list column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, modern-experience, team-sites

I have a list that contains YouTube URLs that I want to display on the page. The user does not need to see these links so I tried to hide the column, but the embed web part can not reference the hidden column. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any workaround to this?

I'm creating a page on a team site using SharePoint online.

Comment: Are you trying to just display the URLs or are you trying to embed the actual YouTube video on the page?

Comment: @CallumCrowley I'm looking to embed the youtube videos based on what the user chooses on a list. I'm trying to hide the URL column of the list.

Comment: There is a YouTube web part, however I don't think it's possible to create a web part connection between a list web part and the YouTube web part unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the **expected behavior** in SharePoint online modern experience.

In order add the reference to the column in list inside the embed web part, you have to show that column in the list view. Hiding the column from list view will not work in this case (The same behavior also applies when using JSON column/view formatting in SharePoint).

Check more information about how you can Show a video, image, or location based on what a user selects in a List web part:

[Show a video, image, or location based on what a user selects in a List web part (connect an Embed web part to a List web part)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec#bkmk_video)